# How can i stop the crawler in parse function

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl the search results.
I have the variable `search_page` which tells on which page number we are at.

I have that variable inside the `parse` function.

Now i want that if the `search_page > 500` then crawler should stop crawling

How can i do that

```
def parse(self, response):

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="headline_area"]')
    items = []

    for site in sites[:5]:
        item = StackItem()
        log.msg(' LOOP' +str(ivar)+ '', level=log.ERROR)
        item['title'] ="yoo ma"
        request =  Request("blabla",  callback=self.test1)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        page_number = nextlink.split("&")[-3].split("=")[-1]
        if page_number > 500:
                 STOP
        ivar = ivar + 1
        yield request
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: have a variable in the caller of `parse` function. increment it in each parse call.

Comment: Replace `STOP` with `break`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html?highlight=closeSpider

from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

```
    if int(page_number) > 500:
       raise CloseSpider('Search Exceeded 500')
```